# How to implement derived state in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
function ScrollView(props) {
  const [isScrollingDown, setIsScrollingDown] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsScrollingDown(props.row)
  }, [props.row])

  // this is a fake function to show its own logic to change the state,
  // and this function could be called in somewhere to make the isScrollingDown
  // state to be a derived state
  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsScrollingDown(false)
  }

  return `Scrolling down: ${isScrollingDown}`;
}
```

In this case, i use the `useEffect` hook to update the derived state in response to a change in props. Can this be a common solution to resolve the derived state in some individual cases. Or if there is any problems in this case?

Comment: If it's derived state, then why do you even need a new stateful variable for it? Why not just say `const isScrollingDown = props.row`?

Comment: Because in the ScrollView component, it has its own logic to update the isScrollingDown state, i did not paste the code and just show the code about its props change.So in this case,  can this  be a common solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, there are no issues with your implementation, as the `isScrollingDown` is merely reacting to the changes of the `row` props value.

However, I do feel that there is no need to use derived state in your scenario, as the logic is rather simple.

It will be much more intuitive to remove the need to maintain the component state and remove any other sources of unnecessary re-rendering.

```
function ScrollView({ row }) {
  return `Scrolling down: ${row}`;
}
```

---

Edit: given that there is actually a need for an internal state, some other optimisations I would suggest would be to carry out a check within the `useEffect` hook such that you are only updating the state when the props and state values differ:

```
useEffect(() => { 
  if (props.row === isScrollingDown {
    return;
  }
  setIsScrollingDown(props.row);
}, [props.row]);
```

Comment: Because in the ScrollView component, it has its own logic to update the isScrollingDown state, i did not paste the code and just show the code about its props change.So in this case,  can this  be a common solution?

Comment: Ahh I see.. Since there is other internal logic that will require you to update the state, I guess you should maintain state then. In that case, yes, it is a valid solution to make use of `useEffect` for that purpose!

Comment: Thank you very much. But if this could be a common solution , [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops), Does it make any sense in this way to implement  getderivedstatefromprops?

Comment: And yes, the tips in that link is useful too. You should consider those things that are written there